# Why does my content not display?

Tags: html, css

Really unsure as to why my HTML content is not displaying inside the divs.

Everything looks correct, It is just not displaying the content.

Here is a snippet:

```css
main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 0; /* Removes White space */
}
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 18vh;
    background-color: orange;
    font-size: 1.8em;
}
aside {
    width: 20%;
    height: 82vh;
    background-color: orange;
    margin: 0 auto;  
    font-size: 1.2em; 
}
section {
    width: 80%;
    height: 82vh;
    background-color: darkgrey;
    margin: 0 auto;   
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px inset; 
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<main id="content">

   <header>
    <h1>Just a random Header</h1>
   </header>

   <aside>
    <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p> 
   </aside>
   
   <section>
    <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p>
    <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p>
    <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p>
    <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p>
   </section>

  </main>
```

Any ideas on how to solve this? It would be really great if my content displayed

Comment: Change `font-size` `em` to `px` Because em calculate with parent. Here parent font size is 0;

Comment: Font-Size: 0; is because of the whitespace issue created using flex, It is a workaround, The em part was my mistake, I forgot it was in proportion to the main font size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have set `font-size: 0;` on the parent wrapper and haven't reset it for the child divs.

*So, when using `em` (which is a proportinal value based on the parent's font size) 1.8em would still be 0 because 1.8 x 0 is still 0.*

It's not necessary when using flexbox anyway. Just remove it.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
main {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 18vh;
  background-color: orange;
}
aside {
  width: 20%;
  height: 82vh;
  background-color: orange;
}
section {
  width: 80%;
  height: 82vh;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px inset;
}
```

```html
<main id="content">

  <header>
    <h1>Just a random Header</h1>
  </header>

  <aside>
    <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p>
  </aside>

  <section>
    <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p>
    <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p>
    <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p>
    <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p>
  </section>

</main>
```

Comment: he has mentioned font-size in section as i can see.. than why browser is taking main's font-size?

Comment: No, he's using `em` which is a proportinal value based on the parent's font size. So 2em would still be 0 because 2*0 is still 0.

Comment: If i comment out mains font size or remove it, Section does not display at all for me, see here - i.imgsafe.org/631ba0d94e.png

Comment: I can't diagnose an image. If my code does not work for you I suggest you ask a NEW question with your revised code. Notice I removed all the margins you had in place as well...they aren't necessary in flexbox either.

Comment: @Paulie_D All i did was what you stated, Plus you say Margins are not needed and you have put * margin: 0 on the css to override all default values, why is this there if Margin is not needed?

Comment: Becuase it was messing with your headings.

Comment: Then surely it is needed?

Comment: So, Your code works primarily for the Header and aside section, yet it does not display anything in the section, not even the background color, which is set in the css - *EDIT* I had to adjust the width on the section, this leaves white space, but that is another question. Thank you

Comment: No, I've rest the margins but the `margin: auto` on the chidl elements is not doing anything under flexbox, Especially as their total widths add up to 100%....so they don't center anything. My guess is you have something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but `main`'s font-size is getting more weightage  than section.

```css
main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    /*font-size: 0;  Removes White space */
}
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 18vh;
    background-color: orange;
    font-size: 1.8em;
}
aside {
    width: 20%;
    height: 82vh;
    background-color: orange;
    margin: 0 auto;  
    font-size: 1.2em; 
}
section {
    width: 80%;
    height: 82vh;
    background-color: darkgrey;
    margin: 0 auto;   
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px inset; 
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<main id="content">

   <header>
    <h1>Just a random Header</h1>
   </header>

   <aside>
    <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p> 
   </aside>
   
   <section>
    <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p>
    <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p>
    <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p>
    <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p>
   </section>

  </main>
```

Comment: If i comment out mains font size or remove it, Section does not display at all for me, see here - https://i.imgsafe.org/631ba0d94e.png

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using `em` as units. And `em` means `# times of current font size` and your current font size is set on `.main {font-size: 0}`

```css
main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 0;
  /* Removes White space */
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 18vh;
  background-color: orange;
  font-size: 18px;
}
aside {
  width: 20%;
  height: 82vh;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 16px;
}
section {
  width: 80%;
  height: 82vh;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px inset;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<main id="content">

  <header>
    <h1>Just a random Header</h1>
  </header>

  <aside>
    <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p>
  </aside>

  <section>
    <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p>
    <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p>
    <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p>
    <p>Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text, Just alot of Random Text</p>
  </section>

</main>
```

Comment: If i use pixels, Then i get alot of white space, hence why the font-size in main is set to 0, it is a workaround when using flex, however when you set the font size in the elements separately it is meant to override the main font-size, take a look https://i.imgsafe.org/631b67f3d3.png

Comment: @Ricky Yes, but `0px * 1.2em = 0`

Comment: I am aware of that, At the time i did not think that would stop the content from displayin, yet it did, Still the answer i accepted has now led to another question, Think i might just give up on flex...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you set the font size to 0 in .main.  In the rest of the code, you are using ems.

The problem is that em units are calculated based on the containing element's font size.  From then on, 1 em = 1 unit of the containing elements font size.  So since you've set the containing elements font size to 0, then no matter what you set it to in the other elements, it will always stay at 0, thus not displaying your text.

Try changing the .main font size to 12px.

Comment: This is what happens when i use pixels https://i.imgsafe.org/631b67f3d3.png, I understand about the ems, but how then if i cannot set font-size to 0 in main to remove white space how do i counteract that?